# Unable to Install PyQt5 sip >=5.0.1 <6

Tags: python, pip, pyqt5

whenever i run pip3 install PyQt5, i get the following error on my m1 mac.

```
ERROR: PyQt5 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7c/5b/e760ec4f868cb77cee45b4554bf15d3fe6972176e89c4e3faac941213694/PyQt5-5.14.0.tar.gz#sha256=0145a6b7de15756366decb736c349a0cb510d706c83fda5b8cd9e0557bc1da72 has a pyproject.toml file that does not comply with PEP 518: 'build-system.requires' contains an invalid requirement: 'sip >=5.0.1 <6'
```

Ive tried, python -m install PyQt3, remaking my virtual env, upgrading pip. But nothing has worked yet. Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by reinstalling, brew and python